# Scaffolding ASP.NET MVC trouble. I get 400 error when I try to edit something

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and I've encountered some problems:

1. First of all, I have added NORTHWIND database to my MVC Project
2. Then I have created some controllers for Customers, Orders, Products etc.
3. To create controllers I used scaffolding with views, using Entity Framework.

I wrote some Action methods:

```
public ActionResult GetAllCustomersWithOrders()
{
    var orders = db.Customers.Where(p => p.Orders.Count > 1).ToList();
    return View(orders);
}

public ActionResult GetAllOrdersFromCustomer()
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Include(p => p.Employee).Include(p => p.Customer).Include(p => p.Shipper).Where(p => p.ShipCity == "Seattle").ToList();
    return View(orders);
}
```

And when I try to edit orders or customers I get 400 error.
Below is what I get after calling action method. When I click edit or anything else I have 400 error.

[image]

What is the cause of that behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show what the error description is ??

Comment: Its bad request error. I can't provide more cause it isn't in english.

Answer (score 0):

You would be having composite primary key for the given model, i.e., more than 1 column as your primary key. In the default views/controllers produced after scaffolding, has single column as its primary key, which is also passed in the method(inside controller)as one of its parameter. So, you need to provide all the columns, as parameters in the action method as well as in your views.
Refer this link for further details. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797444/ASP-NET-MVC-Edit-Primary-Key-Values-for-Composite